# How to show the existence of a curve which shares a tangent with a given vector.

Tags: differential-geometry

If given a vector, $\textbf{a} \in T_p{U}$, where $U\subset\mathbb{R^2}$. How would I show the existence of a curve $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ where $\alpha(0) = p$ and $\dot\alpha(0) = \textbf{a}$?

I mean, it is fairly easy to show the other way, i.e if there exists such a curve then $\textbf{a}$ is a tangent vector at $u$ so is granted entry into $T_p{U}$

But I can not quite get this way, I could define a circle that has p on its perimeter then define a curve who has its maximum distance from the centre of the sphere to be such  a curve. This sounds overcomplicated though.

Comment: That is generally the definition of a tangent vector; what definition of tangent space are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take $\alpha(t) = p + t a$. If that curve is too long replace $t$ by $\phi(t)$ where $\phi$ is identically $1$ near $t=0$ and decays smoothly to $0$ fast enough.